# How to use Mermaid diagram in Jupyter Notebook with mermaid.ink through proxy

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, proxy, mermaid

Prevously to use [Mermaid](https://mermaid.js.org/) in a Jupyter Notebook file, [`nb-mermaid`](https://pypi.org/project/nb-mermaid/) should be installed using `pip` and then it called using built-in magic commands `%%javascript` as instructed [here](https://bollwyvl.github.io/nb-mermaid/) or using `%%html`.

Unfortunately, the result, in a Jupyter Notebook file, [can not be displayed on GitHub](https://gist.github.com/bollwyvl/e51b4e724f0b82669c84), but [will be displayed on nbviewer](https://nbviewer.org/gist/bollwyvl/e51b4e724f0b82669c84). It works only in a GitHub page.

Then there is another way using `mermaid.ink` with IPython as guide in [here](https://mermaid.js.org/config/Tutorials.html#jupyter-integration-with-mermaid-js) as follows.

```py
import base64
from IPython.display import Image, display
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

def mm(graph):
  graphbytes = graph.encode("ascii")
  base64_bytes = base64.b64encode(graphbytes)
  base64_string = base64_bytes.decode("ascii")
  display(
    Image(
      url="https://mermaid.ink/img/"
      + base64_string
    )
  )

mm("""
graph LR;
    A--> B & C & D;
    B--> A & E;
    C--> A & E;
    D--> A & E;
    E--> B & C & D;
""")
```

And it works fine and can be viewed on GitHub as in [here](https://github.com/dudung/py-jupyter-nb/blob/main/src/apply/flowchart/mermaid/begprocend.ipynb).

But when it runs behind proxy the image, which is generated remotely on `https://mermaid.ink/` and display using `matplotlib`, can not be displayed in a Jupyter Notebook file. Is there any solution to this problem?

Comment: This doesn't bode well

Answer (score 3):

It has now been included in JupyterLab 4.1 and Notebook 7.1

- [JupyterLab 4.1 and Notebook 7.1 are here](https://blog.jupyter.org/jupyterlab-4-1-and-notebook-7-1-are-here-20bfc3c10217)

Comment: Thanks @david-davó, but it still does not in Markdown cell nor Code cell as in [here](https://github.com/dudung/py-jupyter-nb/blob/main/src/apply/misc/vacuum/mermaid/mermaid.ipynb). Additionally, there is alternative [mermaid-python](https://pypi.org/project/mermaid-python/). it works locally and rendered on [nbviewer](https://nbviewer.org/github/dudung/py-jupyter-nb/blob/main/src/apply/misc/vacuum/mermaid/mermaid.ipynb), but still can not be rendered on GitHub. It has been tested with or without proxy.

Comment: It works with Markdown cells. In code cells, I used `IPython.display import Markdown` and works too with JupyterLab 4.1, but it doesn't work in GitHub yet.